# Symfony Serialize Entity with Datetime / Deserialize fails

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, deserialization

Im trying to save an Entity as a json file. The entity class also includes a datetime field:

```
class Ear
{
...
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $date;
...
}
```

Then I create a new Ear:

```
$earLine = new Ear();
$earLine->setDate(new \DateTime());
```

Now I simply would think I can normalize and serialize this object:

```
$encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];
$normalizers = [new DateTimeNormalizer(), new ObjectNormalizer()];
$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

$json = $serializer->serialize($earLine, 'json');
```

which works fine. The json looks like this:

```
{
  "id": null,
  "date": "2021-05-31T00:00:00+02:00",
  ...
}
```

However upon trying to deserialize, it fails to **denormalize the datetime**.

```
$encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];
$normalizers = [new DateTimeNormalizer(), new ObjectNormalizer()];
$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

dd($serializer->deserialize($json, Ear::class, 'json'));
```

with the error `Failed to denormalize attribute "date" value for class "App\Entity\Ear": Expected argument of type "DateTimeInterface", "string" given at property path "date".`

I read the docs up and down and search stackoverflow. But it fails for not apparent reason, at least not for me.

Using Symfony 5.3.

Comment: Could you add the serialized JSON to the question?

Comment: I've just tested your code with PHP FPM 7.4.18 and Symfony 4.4.26, it works fine there. For this example my class `Ear` only contained the `date`. Maybe that's useful information for you.

Comment: @KhorneHoly thanks. Updated the post with serialized JSON.

Comment: @KhorneHoly I commented all other properties out for testing purposes. Still the same error: `Serializer->deserialize(array('id' => null, 'date' => '2021-05-31T00:00:00+02:00'), 'App\\Entity\\Ear', 'json')` - running on Devilbox PHP 7.3

Comment: Could you check the uses of the Encoder, Normalizer and Serialier? Maybe you're accidentally using a component from a different bundle instead the symfony one?

Comment: checked multiple times already: 
`use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateTimeNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
`

Comment: I'm not sure If it will help, but I had a similar issue with date (same error) - I was missing `ReflectionExtractor` in `new ObjectNormalizer(null,null,null, new ReflectionExtractor())`, but it was due to presence of relationships/nested entities.