# How to deserialize DateTime in this case?

Tags: symfony

I can't for the life of me figure out how to handle a regular deserialization. I've read dozens of SO questions and also the official doc and it seems to be easy. *Seems.*

I've got a simple JSON, like:

`[{"id":"00112063002463454431","first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","date_of_birth":"2006-09-28"}]`

Now I'd like to map it to my class *Person*. No matter what I've tried, it always complains about *date_of_birth* to be string. It is expected to be DateTimeInterface when the routine internally calls `setDateOfBirth(?DateTimeInterface $dateOfBirth)` inside the Person class. But in my understanding DateTimeNormalizer's *denormalize()* should've already converted it to a DateTime object before it hydrates the Person object, shouldn't it?

Inside my class the field is defined as follows:

```
#[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATE_MUTABLE)]
#[Context([DateTimeNormalizer::FORMAT_KEY => 'Y-m-d'])]
private ?DateTimeInterface $dateOfBirth = null;
```

Deserializing process:

```
    $serializer = new Serializer(
        [new DateTimeNormalizer(), new GetSetMethodNormalizer(), new ArrayDenormalizer()],
        [new JsonEncoder()]
    );

    $personsFromJson = $serializer->deserialize($requestContent, 'App\Entity\Person[]', 'json');
```

Is there anything else to do?!

**Edit**

One-class example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use DateTimeInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Context;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateTimeNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;

class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route(path: '/test', name: 'app_test')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        $json = '{"dateOfBirth":"2023-01-31"}';

        $serializer = new Serializer(
            [new DateTimeNormalizer(), new GetSetMethodNormalizer()],
            [new JsonEncoder()]
        );

        $testPersonFromJson = $serializer->deserialize($json, TestPerson::class, 'json');

        return $this->json($testPersonFromJson);
    }
}

class TestPerson {
    #[Context([DateTimeNormalizer::FORMAT_KEY => 'Y-m-d'])]
    private ?DateTimeInterface $dateOfBirth = null;

    public function getDateOfBirth(): ?DateTimeInterface {
        return $this->dateOfBirth;
    }
    public function setDateOfBirth(?DateTimeInterface $dateOfBirth): self {
        $this->dateOfBirth = $dateOfBirth;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

> App\Controller\TestPerson::setDateOfBirth(): Argument #1
> ($dateOfBirth) must be of type ?DateTimeInterface, string given,
> called in
> [...]\vendor\symfony\serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer.php
> on line 163

The DateTimeNormalizer() gets instantiated, but indeed, denormalize() gets never called.

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe the order of normalizers may matter. Could you try to put them in this order: ArrayDenormalizer, DateTimeNormalizer, GetSetMethodNormalizer ?

Comment: Doesn't change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: I've added an example controller containing my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add a ReflectionExtractor to my ObjectNormalizer. I didn't notice this anywhere.

`new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, new ReflectionExtractor())`

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_info.html#reflectionextractor

Found via the comments after my 18567th search at: [Symfony Serialize Entity with Datetime / Deserialize fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68315133/symfony-serialize-entity-with-datetime-deserialize-fails)